# HTML SVG - Is it possible to import a <svg> into Adobe Illustrator to modify it?

Tags: html, svg

As the title says, how can I modify a svg in Adobe Illustrator?

For example, I got this

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 225 321)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">This a TEST!</text>
<path fill="none" d="M177,246c0,92.859,77.824,168,174,168"/>
<path fill="none" d="M357,246c0,161.398-105.555,292-236,292"/>
<path fill="none" d="M288,414c0,113.311-23.252,205-51.987,205"/>
<rect x="93" y="383" fill="none" width="364" height="147"/>
<g>
    <rect x="167" y="272" fill="none" width="216" height="244.5"/>
</g>
<rect x="476" y="428" fill="none" width="216" height="244.5"/>
<rect x="121" y="230" fill="none" width="403" height="231"/>
<rect x="179" y="158" fill="none" width="362" height="454.25"/>
<rect x="73" y="230" fill="none" width="294" height="184"/>
<rect x="371" y="516.5" fill="none" width="12" height="13.5"/>
<rect x="167" y="143" fill="none" width="221" height="387"/>
</svg>
```

(It doesn't contain anything, its just a random svg).

Do I have to download it as .svg first? And how can I download it as .svg?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a good question & answer, but would be more suitable in graphicdesign stackexchange.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Paste it into a text file named whatever.svg and open that file in Illustrator.

Comment: OMG so easy! Thanks!

Comment: Skip the text file. Paste the SVG code directly into an Illustrator document.

Answer (score 7):

Create a .html document

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">
   <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 225 321)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">This a TEST!</text>
   <path fill="none" d="M177,246c0,92.859,77.824,168,174,168"/>
   <path fill="none" d="M357,246c0,161.398-105.555,292-236,292"/>
   <path fill="none" d="M288,414c0,113.311-23.252,205-51.987,205"/>
   <rect x="93" y="383" fill="none" width="364" height="147"/>
   <g>
    <rect x="167" y="272" fill="none" width="216" height="244.5"/>
   </g>
   <rect x="476" y="428" fill="none" width="216" height="244.5"/>
   <rect x="121" y="230" fill="none" width="403" height="231"/>
   <rect x="179" y="158" fill="none" width="362" height="454.25"/>
   <rect x="73" y="230" fill="none" width="294" height="184"/>
   <rect x="371" y="516.5" fill="none" width="12" height="13.5"/>
   <rect x="167" y="143" fill="none" width="221" height="387"/>
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Open this in the Browser. Open print and press "save as .pdf"

Now you can open this in Illustrator.

[Example](https://www.revilodesign.de/blog/sonstiges/svg-path-zum-bild-umwandeln-konvertieren/)

Comment: This is the perfect solution to export SVG generated or modified by javascript/jquery and use it on Illustrator.

Comment: @Gendrith You can copy outer HTML of the  root SVG element in the developer tools and paste to a blank svg file.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an image from the web, you can right-click 'inspect' and then click and copy [cntrl-c] in windows on the first `<svg>` tag. Then you should be able to directly copy the enitre svg data as an image into illustrator.

If the svg data is not embedded in the web page, you may first need to open up it's link into a new tab or get it from the 'Elements' tab in DevTools.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the SVG code to the clipboard and paste it into your Illustrator document.

Tested on Illustrator 25.

[Source](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/pasting-svg-code-in-illustrator/m-p/10927307)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the image adres and open it in a new tab, open inspector go to sources, find the file(is just one) and save it or drag it to open it in illustrator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).